# Making windows transparent from the software project

Tags: 22.04, hdmi, desktop-environments, window, 23.04

I wrote a very simple software with NOTHING in it but a single window and I made the window transparent with the following code.

```
window.alphablend:=true;
window.alphablendvalue:=133; //0 to 255
```

The software compiles successfully and when it is executed, the software window pops up on the screen transparent. Well, here is my issue.

I have the 2 exact laptops (model number, brand name, etc) running the LATEST UBUNTU on BOTH of them. However, one is just a normal laptop with its own 11inch display and other laptop is connected to a TV through HDMI cable.

When I run this transparent window software on the normal laptop, the window pops up as expected as partially TRANSPARENT. When I take the EXACT copy of this software and run it on the laptop connected to my TV through HDMI connection, the transparent software window pops up but NO TRANSPARENCY AT ALL.

I looked all over the settings in UBUNTU, I couldn't really find anything in there that I could adjust or alter to make this work.

My question why is this happening and how to fix it if there is a way.

EDIT:
There is absolutely nothing in this program. It is just like any programming language that comes with HELLO WORLD sample code.

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
    Classes, SysUtils, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs;

type

{ TForm1 }

TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private

public

end;

var
    Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    self.alphablend:=true;
    self.alphablendvalue:=133; //0 to 255
end;
end.
```

As far as the version goes, it was whatever the version I downloaded at that time when I was doing this test. It was most likely 22.04

Comment: In case this is a free and open source software, can you share the repository?

Comment: We really cannot help much without more details regarding how the transparency works. Please share the source if possible.

Comment: By the way, the latest Ubuntu version is 23.10. You have tagged 22.04, which was the last LTS version (and will be supported for 5 years), but it is not the latest Ubuntu version.